# Restricciones a un input de tipo date

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Soy nuevo en Javascript, y no logro encontrar la manera de que el usuario sólo pueda seleccionar fechas +2 días del día actual, y que sábado y domingo no estén disponibles. Lo único que encontré fue como dar fechas máximas y mínimas

Alguno sabe cómo hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, pude encontrar la solución al problema utilizando el datepicker de bootstrap!

Lo que hay que hacer es incluir los archivos .js y .css del datepicker, y luego colocar, por ejemplo, un código como el siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group date nf-date">

                        <span class="input-group-addon">

                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>

                        </span>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroCalendario" name="registroCalendario" placeholder="Día de envío" required>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Eso sería el campo que contiene al calendario dentro del formulario.
Luego, en Javascript se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
/*=============================================
CALENDARIO BOOTSTRAP
=============================================*/

$('.nf-date').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    weekStart: 0,
    startDate: "+2d",
    endDate: "+30d",
    clearBtn: true,
    language: "es",
    multidate: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Con startDate: "+2d" le digo que solo esté disponible a partir de 2 días después a la fecha actual, y con daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6" deshabilito sábados y domingos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

`<input type="date" name="bday" max="2018-11-05" min="2018-11-03">`

Min: para el minimo posible
Max: para el maximo posible
Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias!! @Bryro